# How to get the id of the logined google user from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Without using oauth2.
Because I don't want to get any user's data or do an authentication, only get the id.
And I want to monitor login/logout (chrome.identity.onSignInChanged does not work).
ps I need ID for storing data on my server (chrome.storage.sync is too small).

Comment: What do you mean by "ID of the google user" ?

Comment: The id of the user who's logined in chrome at the moment.

Comment: BTW, unless you require the user to log into your server as well (either directly or indirectly), I hope you are not storing sensitive user data :)

Comment: No, it is public data.

Answer (score 1):

You say you dont want to use oauth because you dont need any user data. However the id or email IS user data and there's an oauth scope just for that. Use it, else the other alternatives might break in the future, or wait until chrome identity is out for all.

Another way if you really dont want oauth is to store a random number in chrome sync and use that as your id. If the random is large enough you will avoid collitions in practice. Prepend the random with the current millseconds since 1970 and I bet there will be no collitions.

Comment: I think I will use the idea of generated id. Thanks.

Comment: Well what if we don't need the email? I don't think it makes sense to get a precious information like email just because there's no 'id' scope. 
Random generated doesn't work because I want to verify this 'id' (token that gets the id) on the phone over SSL on google servers.

Comment: you get the id by using any scop. i think the userinfo scope has that and no email.

Answer (score -1):

**[chrome.identity.onSignInChanged](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity.html#event-onSignInChanged)** is not working (as you mentioned), because it is currently available on the `dev` channel only (according to **[this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310753&q=onSignInChanged&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)** and other sources online).
So, with a little bit of luck, it will be available on the `stable` channel soon...

A little hacky, but (as suggested in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887770/google-chrome-sync-check-if-enabled-via-api-extension#answer-15351748)**) you could make an AJAX requests to `https://www.google.com/settings/account` and parse the content to extract the info about user being logged in and user e-mail.
(That's not very robust, of course, since the e-mail might change, but maybe good enough for a temporary work-around.)

Comment: DO NOT do that. Google will not like you nor your extension ;) Especially if you don't know what you're doing and you cause infinite loops with your requests... You'll just harm the users of your extension.

Comment: @AdamWos: I don't really see how you could cause infinite loops or why Google would hate you for making a request. That said, I already mention in my answer it is a _hacky, temporary workaround_, I mention the proper way to handle it (`chrome.identity.onSignInChanged`), I explain why it wasn't working at the time and that it should be available on stable soon (indeed it is available since version 33). I don't really see a reason for downvoting, nor do I agree with your comment ! Just saying...

Comment: Well, if I could point fingers, I would :) I'll just say, there are people who somehow managed to get this wrong, did use such a mechanism, and caused some of their extension's users some hardship. Also, you might want to read this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en. And also, the question (as clarified) was for a *logged-in Chrome user*, not the user logged in inside the content view. These can be different users, and [the second half of] your answer gives the author the latter.